# Converting vintage lense to digital camera

Tags: lens

I have a Canon Rebel EOS Rebel sl1 100D camera. I have an older Sigma APO 170-500 lense.  Can this be used on the digital camera with an adapter and which adapter? I have looked everywhere and frankly not experienced enough to understand most of what I'm reading other than you can but the autofocus won't work have to do manual. I don't want to ruin my camera plus I can't find anywhere which adapter it would be if I do try to do this. Anyone's help I would appreciate. Thanks

Comment: Sigma, as a 3rd-party lens manufacturer, created lenses for a wide variety of lens mounts. Your first task is to find out [what camera mount](https://blog.keh.com/the-lens-mount-guide-part-1/) the Sigma lens was designed for.

Comment: Suggest editing the question to ask a variation of "what mount is this?" Add a picture of the lens mount. Otherwise, agree with inkista re duplicate.

Comment: See also [Which vintage lens mount is most suitable for EOS cameras?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/103000/75526)

Comment: It seems this lens has been made for Canon EF (might work without any adapter and with AF, might need rechipping), Pentax PK (there are mechanical adapters, will be fully manual), Nikon F (same), Sony/Minolta A mount (difficult, flange distances too close....) and Sigma SA (uncommon, probably difficult) ....